# When to throw exception and when return unmodified original parameter value?

Tags: java, exception

I am working of Utility class and one method in this class accepts a content (`String`) and id (`int`) as parameters, transforms content a returns it back to the client.

I am validating input (content cannot be blank and id must be positive), and in this stage I am not sure what to do if some of these expectations is not met. Is better to return original, unmodified content `String` or throw an appropriate exception that tells to the client that input has not been valid?

```
public String prepareContent(String content, long taskItemId) {

    if (Validator.notBlank(content) == false || Validator.isPositive(taskItemId) == false) {
        // what to do here? return content or throw an exception?
    }

    // some modification stuff....

    return content;

}
```

What is the best way of handling these situations?

EDIT: For example a [replace](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method from Apache StringUtils library returns unmodified original value instead of throwing an exception. What is a purpose of this...?

```
 public static String replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement, int max) {
        if (isEmpty(text) || isEmpty(searchString) || replacement == null || max == 0) {
            return text;
        }
       // omitted...
    }
```

Comment: You can throw exception . that would be proper idea

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - yes, it depends, but try to be more specific, please.

Answer (score 2):

When a bad argument is passed into your method the convention is to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (which is a `RuntimeException`) - see [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) for details - which you can also extend to your liking.

Returning the content unmodified is probably not a good idea, as it might lead to bugs further down your chain of processing.

If, however, the operation allows the returned `Object` to be equal in reference or value to the argument, e.g. when a replacement argument is not found, then you may want to return the argument instead.

Ultimately, a good javadoc specification for your method will win over any ambiguity that your implementation might cause.

Comment: For illustration I'have just added another example when library returns an original value.

Comment: @user2148736 edited my answer. As others pointed out, it depends :) Document your code and you should be all right.

Comment: I can not agree, in the Documentation you should have simple description of how the method behave. But not listed each exception cause as it is impossible. You can abstract and determine for what input algorithm will produce equal output. And for those cases you can return input with out running algorithm. Same ref. in input that break the alg. an could cause a invalid result. In such case you thrown an exception. So its depend but on some deterministic level that you can implement in your code.

Comment: @Vash I've never said you should document each exception cause. I'm just saying that returning the same `Object` as your argument is an option if documented.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to claim that it depends but you can apply some logic into the decision. The decision when to throw an exception or when to result unmodified input can be based on assumption.

- In case we have a algorithm that form given input produce output and output is equal to input in other words there is no effect, then algorithm does not have to be executed.
- In case the input parameter do not allow to operate algorithm in deterministic way an error should be reported.

Those two sentences may assist you to make decision when to throw and when to return unmodified value.

In case of the passed example from Apache.

The method `replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement, int max)`, task is to replace in `text` value that match to `searchString` with value of 'replacement' and the operation should be performed `max` times.

From this we can in deterministic (always the same) way state that.

- In case the value of text is empty, no replace can take place. So no matter what are other parameters the result will be always the same.
- In case the value of `searchString` is empty we will not find anything to replace there for no replacement will occur.
- In case the value of `replacement` is `null`. We deal with developer choice, it would be fair to throw an exception as you can not put `null` into a string. But from the same reason no change will take place.
- In case the value of `max` is equal to zero no replacement will take place.

All above statement map to the conditions that method use to return unchanged input as result. They are deterministic as they are always true.

In case of your method, you have some rules that output must meet. Those are it can not be empty and must be positive. So in case the input is positive and the modification will not change it then you can return it as is.

Comment: Thanks, your comment make me sense the most. But there is only "you can", I would like to find some rule and use it for another cases. Btw. what do you think with "in deterministic way"? And back to method pro Apache, why they don't throw an exception but return unmodified value?

Comment: I have edited my post. Hope that helps. Regarding the "you can". There are no common rules that you can reuse. The rules definition depend on the expected result you want to have. So you can not create deterministic rule for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

When designing an API you should think not only on what your method does, but also, how others are going to use your method.

Think about if the caller of the method will need to be notified if the validation is not passed, or it can continue anyway with the unmodified content.

If they can continue with the unmodified content, just return it.

If not, your method must notified the callers that the validation is not passed and returning and exception is a perfect way to do it.

Another option if validations are a common task in your program is use a class for the validations instead a method.

```
public class PrepareContent {

    public static boolean isValid(String content, long taskItemId) {
        // ...
    }

    // @returns InvalidParameterException if the input is not valid
    public static String prepareContent(String content, long taskItemId) {
        if (!isValid(String content, long taskItemId) throw new InvalidParameterException();
        // ..
    }
}
```

The code can be improved but is just to provide a different idea of how to do it. If you use an interface for your validation class, then it will be easily extensible and modificable.